# Want a save-as-or-run popup in Wordpress - html tag a

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following line of html code in my Wordpress site which downloads an .exe file into the downloads folder without prompting the user with a save-as-or-run popup.  How can I change it to get that popup?  Based on my searching I think maybe there's supposed to be a popup with this code and maybe I need to change something else like .htaccess but I couldn't tell for sure from the sites I looked at.  Please advise.

```
href=http://mywebsite.com/mysetup.exe download>CLICK HERE TO DOWNLOAD A .EXE FILE</a>
```

Comment: It's a browser configured behaviour, you have no influence on that.

Comment: I see.  Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way to get a popup that will allow me to run an .exe file without saving it first?

Comment: No, browser decides what they do themselves.